# Is there something wrong with my react table code? I cannot see my table

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
<div class = "sampleTable">




const TableBody = props => { 
    const rows = props.fillTheData.map((row, index) => {
        return (
            <tr key={index}>
                <td>{row.name}</td>
                <td>{row.job}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    });

    return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const character = [
            {
                'name': 'Charlie',
                'job': 'Janitor'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Mac',
                'job': 'Bouncer'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Dee',
                'job': 'Aspring actress'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Dennis',
                'job': 'Bartender'
            }
    ];
    return(

        <Table characterData = {character}/>

    )
  }
}

class Table extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const {characters} = this.props;
    return(
      <table>
        <TableHeader />
        <TableBody fillTheData = {characters} />
      </table>
    )
  }
}

const TableHeader = () => { 
    return (
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Job</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("sampleTable"))
```

I want to create a table without directly using HTML. Instead, choosing to react to do this task is my purpose. I checked several times, but I still do not know what happened in the code because I cannot see the table.

Right now, we have a cool Table component, but the data is being hard-coded. One of the big deals about React is how it handles data, and it does so with properties, referred to as props, and with state. First, we’ll focus on handling data with props.

Then let’s move all that data to an array of objects, as if we were bringing in a JSON-based API. We’ll have to create this array inside our render().

Answer (score 0):

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const character = [
            {
                'name': 'Charlie',
                'job': 'Janitor'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Mac',
                'job': 'Bouncer'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Dee',
                'job': 'Aspring actress'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Dennis',
                'job': 'Bartender'
            }
        ];
        return (

            <Table characters={character} />  <--- replace the props name with 'characters'

        )
    }
}
```

The reason why your code is not working is because you are passing a prop called `characterData` down to `Table`, but inside of `Table`, you are destructuring `characters` from `this.prop`, which will gives you `undefined` as you have never passed a prop named `characters` to the `Table` Component.

Comment: Thank you so much Ray! But I think "this.props" can represent characterData and pass it to {characters}. Sorry I did not get it : (

Comment: Yes, from your code, the `Table` component will receives a prop called `characterData` because you passed down a prop with the same name in the line `<Table characterData = {character}/>`. However, you haven't passed a prop named `characters`, so `Table` will not know there is a prop named `characters`. The name of props being passed down is determined by the left hand side of the `=` sign, while the value of that prop is given by the right hand side of the `=` sign.

Comment: And the line for destructuring `const {characters} = this.props;` is essentially doing `const characters = this.props.characters`. But you haven't pass anything to `Table` with a prop named `characters`, so `const characters` will be assigned a value of `undefined`

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you so much for your time and effort Ray! : )